# Constructing a odd homeomorphism between $A$ and $S^n$.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{0\}$ be a closed symmetric set ($x\in A$ then $-x\in A$). Suppose that $A$ is homeomorphic to some sphere $S^n$, $n\leq N$ ($n$ is the dimension of the sphere). Is it possible to construct a homeomorphism $F:A\to S^n$ such that $F$ is odd?

Update: this problem was solved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152099/constructing-a-odd-homeomorphism-between-a-and-sn).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea, but I don't see how to finish it. You have a homeomorphism $f\colon A\to S^n$, and this induces an involution $\alpha\colon S^n\to S^n$ given by $f(x)\mapsto f(-x)$. Using a variant of [Alexander's trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick), one can show that $\pi_0({\rm Homeo}(S^n))\cong \mathbb Z_2$, with the two classes represented by orientation-reversing and orientation-preserving homeomorphisms, respectively. Therefore $\alpha$ is isotopic to the antipodal map $x\mapsto -x$ provided that it does the same thing to orientation as the antipodal map. Notice that $\alpha$ is fixed-point free. So the Lefschetz trace must be zero. In this simple case of spheres, the Lefschetz trace of a homeomorphism $f$ is $1+(-1)^n\deg f$. So $\deg \alpha=(-1)^{n+1}$, which is the same as the degree of the antipodal map. Therefore $\alpha$ is isotopic to the antipodal map. If $\alpha$ were *ambient isotopic* to the antipodal map we'd be done, since an ambient isotopy $H\colon S^1\times I\to S^n$ would be a function where $H(x,0)=x$ and $H(\alpha(x),1)=-x$. So letting $g(x)=H(x,1)$ the map $gf\colon A\to S^n$ would commute withe the antipodal map, as desired. Thus we are left with the problem of promoting an isotopy to an ambient isotopy, which is not always possible. Indeed, Alexander's trick creates nasty singularities, which might mean that it can't be done in general. If you switch to ${\rm Diff}(S^n)$ rather than ${\rm Homeo}(S^n)$, you could probably assume that isotopies are promotable to ambient isotopies, but $\pi_0({\rm Diff}(S^n))$ would become more complicated. Indeed, for $n\geq 5$, $\pi_0({\rm Diff}^+(S^n))\cong\Theta_{n+1}$, the group of exotic $(n+1)$-spheres. So if you're going to find a counterexample, $n+1$ will have to be at least $7$, when the first exotic spheres occur.

Comment: I was thinking something like this too. If there is some counter example, it must be some kind of exotic sphere. At least now, I know that there is possibility to exist such example. On the other hand (at least for me) this is so anti-intuitive...

Comment: Well that's a possibility too. $A$ could be an exotic sphere. Or the map $A\to A$ induces by $x\to-x$ could be an exotic diffeomorphism of a standard sphere. This seems like a pretty hard question.

Comment: Dear @grumpyparsnip, please take a look here:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152099/constructing-a-odd-homeomorphism-between-a-and-sn

Comment: @Tomás: thanks for the link!

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about the first example occurring in dimension 7.